# VLAN setup via command line works, ifcfg-ethX.Y does not (CentOS 6.8)

Tags: centos, vlan

I have CentOS 6.8 running in a Parallels VM. eth0 is bridged to the Ethernet adapter in the Mac. I need the CentOS server running a specific VLAN (10), so I have read [this RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_802.1Q-vlan-tagging.html).

eth0 pulls a DHCP address (for the moment) and I can ping the equipment on the untagged network OK from within the VM. I have tried the following with eth0 set static and not assigning it an address, but without a difference for the VLAN accessibility.

However, when I setup an ifcfg-eth0.10 with

```
VLAN=yes
DEVICE=eth0.10
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=10.10.2.10
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
```

I am unable to ping anything on VLAN 10, including other virtual interfaces on the Mac host. If, however, I do this ([as documented here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Configure_802_1Q_VLAN_Tagging_Using_the_Command_Line.html)):

```
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.10 type vlan id 10
```

followed by

```
ip addr add 10.10.2.10 dev eth0.10
```

I am immediately able to use the interface as expected. That's great! But I need the VLAN interface to persist after a restart. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For persisted VLAN you need to setup 802.1Q VLAN tagging using [ifcfg files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-Configure_802_1Q_VLAN_Tagging_Using_the_Command_Line#sec-Setting_Up_802.1Q_VLAN_Tagging_Using_ifcfg_Files)